# Probability data structure

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, data-structures

The Idea is to have a data structure that you can access its elements only randomly, but based on a probability factor defined by the user for each element.  So if the probability of the structure that contains 100 elements to yield `x` is 0.5, then, theoretically if we try to retrieve a random element a hundred times then `x` will be returned about \~50 times.

I couldn't find a ready-solution that does this, so this is my take on it:

```
import kotlin.math.absoluteValue

/**
 *@author mhashim6 on 13/10/2019
 */
class ProbabilitySet<T>(private val items: Array<out Pair<T, Float>>) {
    private var probabilityIndices: List<Int>

    private fun calcFutureSize(count: Int, probability: Float) =
            ((count / (1f - probability)) - count).toInt().absoluteValue

    init {
        probabilityIndices = items.withIndex().flatMap { (i, item) ->
             item.act { (_, probability) ->
                calcFutureSize(items.size, probability).minus(items.size).act { delta ->
                    Iterable { ConstIterator(delta, i) }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun next(): T = items.random().first
}

class ConstIterator(private var size: Int, private val const: Int) : IntIterator() {

    override fun nextInt(): Int {
        size--
        return const
    }

    override fun hasNext(): Boolean = size > 0

}

fun <E> probabilitySetOf(vararg items: Pair<E, Float>) = ProbabilitySet(items)

inline fun <T, R> T.act(action: (T) -> R) = action(this)
```

I tried to make it mutable, but I met a lot of complexities regarding time and memory. So it's immutable for now.

Is this a viable Implementation? 
Is there an implementation for this problem already?
How to make it mutable?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How should the data structure behave if the sum of probabilities isn't equal to _1_? Should it assume that actual item probability is `probability / sum`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that if the sum of elements' probabilities is not equal to *1*, the actual element probability must be calculated by dividing its original probability by a sum of all elements' probabilities. For example, `ProbabilitySet` consisting of `"A" to 0.1F` and `"B" to 0.3F` returns `"A"` in *25%* of cases and `"B"` in *75%* of cases.

Here is my implementation of mutable `ProbabilitySet` with `add` running in *O(1)* and `next` running in *O(logN)*:

```
class ProbabilitySet<E>(
    private val random: Random = Random.Default
) {
    private val nodes = mutableListOf<Node>()
    private var sum = 0F

    fun add(element: E, probability: Float) {
        require(probability >= 0) { "[$element]'s probability ($probability) is less than 0" }
        val oldSum = sum
        sum += probability
        nodes += Node(oldSum..sum, element)
    }

    fun isEmpty() = sum == 0F

    fun next(): E {
        if (isEmpty()) throw NoSuchElementException("ProbabilitySet is empty")
        val index = random.nextFloat() * sum
        return nodes[nodes.binarySearch {
            when {
                it.range.start > index -> 1
                it.range.endInclusive < index -> -1
                else -> 0
            }
        }].element
    }

    private inner class Node(
        val range: ClosedRange<Float>,
        val element: E
    )
}
```

Factory method:

```
fun <E> probabilitySetOf(vararg items: Pair<E, Float>, random: Random = Random.Default) =
    ProbabilitySet<E>(random).apply {
        items.forEach { (element, probability) -> add(element, probability) }
    }
```

Use case:

```
val set = probabilitySetOf("A" to 0.4F, "B" to 0.3F)
println(set.next())
set.add("C", 0.9F)
println(set.next())
```